# Как изменить стиль дива, при нажатии на textarea

Tags: css

Есть див, в котором находится textarea

```
        <div class="card-content block-add-feed">
            <div class="card-body">
                <textarea placeholder="Что у Вас нового?" v-model="description" class="form-control desc-feed" id="description" rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button @click="update" class="btn btn-primary text ml-2 mb-2" v-if="!is_refresh">Отправить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

По умолчанию этот див 'свернут'
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал 'разворачивание' дива при наведении на него мышкой

```
.block-add-feed {
  height: 65px;
}
.block-add-feed:hover {
  height: 175px;;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
+ справа от кнопки будут располагаться прикрепленные файлы, их кол-во не ограниченно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как сделать 'разворачивание' дива, при нажатии на textarea?
Пробовал использовать

```
 .block1:hover ~ .block2 h1 { color: red;}
```

Но как я понял, оба блока должны находиться внутри одного элемента, в моем случаи они лежат в разных местах

Comment: В css нельзя выбирать элементы вверх. Но в вашем случае можно попробовать решить например псевдоэлементом и им манипулировать, но все элементы в форме должны быть жестко зафиксированны по высоте

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Жестко зафиксированы, это то есть textarea не должны менять свою высоту? + в примере не указал, справа от кнопки будут располагаться файлы(могут и не быть) дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, менять высоту нельзя, но css это костыльное решение, добавил ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта тема уже поднималась не раз. Но, пока нет CSS-реализации `parent()` - только JS/jQ и `parentElement` или `closest()`.
Если это единичная форма на странице, то инлайн Вам в помощь. Для более сложных проверок и условий, лучше вешать обработчик в основных скриптах.

```css
.block-add-feed {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dotted #090;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-content block-add-feed">
  <div class="card-body">
    <textarea 
      placeholder="Что у Вас нового?" 
      v-model="description" 
      class="form-control desc-feed" 
      id="description" 
      rows="3" 
      required 
      onfocus="this.closest('.block-add-feed').style.height='175px';" 
      onblur="this.parentElement.parentElement.style.height='20px';"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button @click="update" class="btn btn-primary text ml-2 mb-2" v-if="!is_refresh">Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с css только такой:

```css
.card-content {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.card-content textarea {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
}

.height-helper {
  height: 20px;
  transition: height .2s;
}

textarea:focus~.height-helper {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-content block-add-feed">
  <div class="card-body">
    <textarea placeholder="Что у Вас нового?" v-model="description" class="form-control desc-feed" id="description" rows="3" required></textarea>
    <div class="height-helper"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button @click="update" class="btn btn-primary text ml-2 mb-2" v-if="!is_refresh">Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В вашем случае точно лучше будет на js сделать изменение класса всего блока на фокусе. Тк тут плавает высота от дополнительных блоков.